# Create a SAML2 Response in c#/Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml, saml-2.0

I have been asked to implement a Single Sign On solution to enable our users to connect to a 3rd party service without logging on again.

As I understand it the requirement is:

1. User logs in to our web server using Active Directory
2. Server constructs a SAML 2 response
3. This is then seamlessly posted to the third party app which should now allow them in.

I am totally new to SAML and a little confused by all the terminology.  Can someone possibly point me in the direction of some example code that does this, ideally using the .Net4.5 (or greater) libraries.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a SAML stack.

Refer : [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html)

There's a lot of documentation in the links.

Just to call out from the post:

"There is **NO** official Microsoft C# client-side SAML protocol stack."

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. Especially knowing there is no official solution is really important.

Comment: That post appears to be pretty old. The [currrent System.IdentityModel.Tokens Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains `Saml2*` classes that didn't exist as recently as the [.NET 4 version of the namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: No - that post is NOT pretty old. Yes - there are SAML classes but they are for tokens not for protocol. .